# Python kivy double tap

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making an App in Python kivy, and I have a draggable Image. Whenever a user double taps on the draggable image it prints "this is a double tap".

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class DragImage(DragBehavior, Image):
    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        uid = self._get_uid()
        if uid in touch.ud:
        return super(DragImage, self).on_touch_up(touch)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and touch.is_double_tap:
            print('this is a double tap')
        return super(DragImage, self).on_touch_down(touch)

class TacScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Why are you using `size_hint` of `1`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson, that's because it's the perfect size that I'm looking for!

Comment: The `y` part of the `size_hint` (`.1`) is setting the size, because `keep_ratio` is the default value of `True`. The `x` part of the `size_hint` ('1') is causing  your trouble and does not affect the size of the picture you are seeing.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, If i set the x part of the size_hint to "0" the image disappears

Comment: Don't set it to `0`. if your `Tv.png` is a square picture, then set the `x` part to the same as the `y` part: `size_hint: .1, .1`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, I just tried this, same problem even If I double tap outside the image it print's "this is a double tap"

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions of `Tv.png`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson, it's 512x512

Comment: Try using `size_hint: None, .1`, and adding `width: self.height`. This will keep the `Image` square.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, this helps a little, but still If I double tap outside the Image it prints "this is a double tap" also it changes the position of the image.

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't use `size_hint` for positioning. Use `pos` for that. And now your `drag_rectangle` can go back to the simpler `drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height`.

Comment: There must be something else going on if you are getting `double tap` outside the `Image`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, If I change the size_hint to "None .1 and add width: self.height whenever I resize my screen the image moves.

Comment: Is it actually moving, or is it staying at the original `pos` and the background is changing behind it?

Comment: @JohnAnderson, it's the background

Comment: @JohnAnderson, I have posted a new question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your `<DragImage>` rule in the `kv` to:

```
DragImage
    id: tv
    pos: 0, 102
    size_hint: None, .1
    width: self.height
    source: "Tv.png"
```

Then the `DragImage` will stay square and the picture will fill the `Image` widget (if the `Tv.png` is a square picture).

When the `Window` is resized, the `DragImage` will stay in the same `pos`, but will not stay in the same location relative to the background image. One way to keep the `DragImage` stationary is to use `pos_hint`, but that will not allow dragging. You can keep the `DragImage` stationary relative to the background by adding a `on_size()` method to `TacScreen`:

```
class TacScreen(Screen):
    old_size = ListProperty([800, 600])  # keeps track of previous size

    def on_size(self, screen, new_size):
        if self.old_size != new_size:
            di = self.ids.tv  # get the DragImage
            # move the DragImage to keep it stationary relative to background
            di.pos = new_size[0] * di.x / self.old_size[0], new_size[1] * di.y / self.old_size[1]
        self.old_size = new_size
```

Comment: this works! One more thing, whenever I double tap on the draggable Image I want to input text just below the draggable Image, and when I drag the Image I want the text to drag with it as well. How can I do that? If you want I can post a new question! Thank You!

Comment: Yes, post a new question.

Comment: I have posted a new question, any help is appreciated! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the on_press inside your image.

```py
DragImage
        id: tv
        pos: 0, 102
        size_hint: 1, .1
        source: "Tv.png"
        on_press: root.tap_count()
```

Now you can set a variable to count the taps in your image, starting on zero.

```py
class DragImage(DragBehavior, Image):
    count = 0
   
    def tap_count(self):
        count += 1
        if count == 2:
            count = 0
            print("this is a double tap")

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        uid = self._get_uid()
        if uid in touch.ud:
        return super(DragImage, self).on_touch_up(touch)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and touch.is_double_tap:
            print('this is a double tap')
        return super(DragImage, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

I can't test this right now but in theory it will work

Comment: @ATEKO this doesn't work!